# Android customview does not invalidate margins in onlayout or ondraw

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, ondraw, margins, invalidation

I am having a problem with a custom view (which is a RelativeLayout) I made for an android app (API 8).
I have implemented a custom view that displays small images on a canvas. This all works fine, except the first time the view is drawn.

The positions of the images are scaled after the first measurement. The correct coordinates are given in the `onDraw` and `onLayout` functions, but the views are still drawn on the non-scaled positions. If you turn the screen on and off again the views are drawn on the correct position. However, I cannot seem to trigger a redraw myself.
Below is a snippet of the `onLayout` code.

```
calculateMeasurements();
int x = (int) (v.getPositionX()*scaleX+offset[1]);
int y = (int) (v.getPositionY()*scaleY+offset[0]);

Log.w("View.onLayout", "__Creating v: (orig)(" + v.getPositionX()+","+v.getPositionY() + ")"+ 
"\n      (scaled)(" + x +","+y+")");    

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)foto_views.get(v.getIdentifier()).getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
foto_views.get(v.getIdentifier()).setLayoutParams(params);  

Log.e("OpstellingView.onLayout" , " Layoutparams: ("
+((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)foto_views.get(v.getIdentifier()).getLayoutParams()).leftMargin + " ,"
+ ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)foto_views.get(v.getIdentifier()).getLayoutParams()).topMargin + " ,"
); 

foto_views.get(v.getIdentifier()).requestLayout();
foto_views.get(v.getIdentifier()).invalidate();
this.invalidate();
```

In `calculateMeasurements()`, the correct scales are calculated.
I know it gets to `onLayout` and `onDraw` (and has the correct coordinates) because LogCat shows it in the log, but as I said the views are not drawn at the correct place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an AsyncTask to load the images, and now the margins are displayed correctly. I still don't know why this works, but it does. I think it is because a `ProgressDialog` forces the view to redraw itself.